# Woocommerce product count on taxonemy pages, always page count +1 and pagination only shows next page. AWS, Nginx, HHVM, Aurora

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, woocommerce, amazon-aurora

Take a look at this link

https://staging.crowdyhouse.com/product-category/home-accessories/

The product count says 37 which is 36 (amount of products per page ) + 1

This problem does not exist on my local machine where the count is 1955 and should be around the same on staging and production.

Due to this count being wrong the pagination is also broken, only showing the next page.

On page 2 the count is 73 (2 X 36) + 1.

As the problem does not exist on my local I can't see this being a coding issue, though its seems to have happened after the update to Woocommerce 3.0.5. That being said I have disabled all plugins other than Woocommerce and tried two different themes, but no change.

The main differences between my local and the staging server are we use RDS Aurora for the database, and the version of hhvm is different. I believe the issue is somewhere in the Aurora database.

I have tried exporting the database and installing it on the local version of mysql on the ec2 instance, and this has worked but this is not a permanent solution.

I have then tried rebooting the Aurora instance, RESET QUERY CACHE and mysqlcheck --repair / --optimize. None of these have made any difference.

Does any one have anymore suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a problem with Aurora Database.

It had a bug with mysql call FOUND_ROWS() which is used in a core function of Wordpress.

After speaking to the AWS support an update was released (Aurora version 1.13) and the problem was fixed.